# Unable to get past login page using jsoup

Tags: forms, apache, jsoup

I am unable to get the desired response using jsoup to login and scrape the referred page.

I am trying to access a page called `https://localhost/private/frontpage.do` , and I can see that the POST method is `POST security_check` which I gleaned via firebug with the parameters `password=guest&username=guest&submit=`.

When I use the following code I still am unable to get to the desired page.

```
Response res = Jsoup
            .connect("https://localhost/private/security_check")
            .data("j_username", "guest")
            .data("j_password", "guest")
            .referrer("https://localhost/private/frontpage.do")
            .data("submit", "")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
Document doc = res.parse();

    String sessionId = res.cookie("SESSIONID");

    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://localhost/private/frontpage.do")
            .cookie("SESSIONID", sessionId)
            .get();
```

I received the following POST location and parameters from firebug as follows `https://localhost/private/j_security_check?password=guest&username=guest&submit=`

Any idea why I cant see the new page, but get a HTTP error instead in Java `Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=408`

Comment: The URL you found in firebug looks like it is using GET. Are you certain that the method should be POST?

Comment: The NET specification shows `POST SECURITY_CHECK` so from my guess this is post method.